# Make Bootstrap navbar-nav slide horizontally when viewport width is greater than 768px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've navbar with 9 elements inside, when viewport width is less than 768px everything is ok, but when viewport is larger than 768px it looks like this:

[Image that show navbar http://imageshack.com/a/img537/967/vOZFCK.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/967/vOZFCK.jpg)

My goal is to make navbar-nav scrollable horizontally, and the sixth, the seventh and eighth element must appear in line with the other and and everything must be scrollable.

The effect is similar to that visible [here](http://smoothtouchscroll.com/), so I tried to implement Smooth Touch Scroll Jquery plugin, adding `<div id="TouchScroller"></div>` before navbar-nav div,but nothing happens.

Please help me!

Here Navbar Html code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-lezard">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                    <h1>Lezard <span class="orange">Climb</span></h1>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-lezard">
            <div id="TouchScroller">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about"><span class="yellow">Chi siamo</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#dove"><span class="blu">Dove siamo</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contatti"><span class="green">Contattaci</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#attivita"><span class="orange">Attività</span></a>
                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#orari"><span class="violet">Orari</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#corsi"><span class="light-blu">Corsi di arrampicata</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#abbonamenti"><span class="red">Abbonamenti</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#staff"><span class="brown">Staff Lezard</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```css
.navbar{
    border-bottom: none !important;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive,helvetica,sans-serif;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 2em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px ) {
  .form-panel-width{
    width: 100%; 
    }
}
.navbar-brand{
    margin-top: -1.6em;
    margin-left: -0.7em;
}
.navbar-toggle{
    margin-top: 0.4em;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color: #ff9900;
    border-color: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle:active{
   background-color: #ff9900;
   border-color: transparent;
}
.icon-bar {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
.navbar-nav > li{
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}
/*Fix Navbar element when height is too low */
@media screen and (max-height: 380px) and (max-width: 767px){
    .navbar-nav > li{
        margin-bottom: -0.4em;
    }
}
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (min-height: 1024px){
    .navbar-nav{
        margin-top: 1.5em;
    }
    .navbar-brand{
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .navbar-brand h1{
        font-size: 3em;
    }
    .navbar-nav a{
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where's the style sheet?

Comment: I added the style sheet